# HQL "is null" And "!= null" on an Oracle column

Tags: oracle, hibernate, null

Does *hibernate* convert `column != null` in *HQL* to a `column is null` in *SQL*?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

That is a binary operator in hibernate you should use

```
is not null
```

Have a look at [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 44):

No. You have to use `is null` and `is not null` in HQL.

Answer (score 17):

If you do want to use `null` values with `'='` or `'<>'` operators you may find the

> [answer from @egallardo hier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593066/1860309)

very useful.

Short example for `'='`: The expression

```
WHERE t.field = :param
```

you refactor like this

```
WHERE ((:param is null and t.field is null) or t.field = :param)
```

Now you can set the parameter `param` either to some non-null value or to `null`:

```
query.setParameter("param", "Hello World"); // Works
query.setParameter("param", null);          // Works also
```

Comment: Right answer, but a bit overkill :) I do it if I have no other solutions: If there is only one or two nullable param, i find it better to make many HQL or JPQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

No. See also this link [Handle conditional null in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593066/761918) for tips and tricks on how to handle comparisons with both null and non-null values.