# Null in HQL Expressions

Tags: java, hibernate, null, hql

I want to know if HQL expressions are null-safe or not?
For example, consider this named query

```
SELECT a
FROM A a
where a.f=:f
```

in which f is a field of type String, Double, Date, etc.
Then I use it like:

```
session.getNamedQuery("myNamedQuery").setString("f", myFValue).uniqueResult();
```

If both a.f and myFValue are null I want the condition to be true and if just one of them is null I want it to be false.

If it is not null-safe, how can I handle that?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

They are not. Try these scenarios out to handle your specific case:

`select a from A a where ((:f is null and a.f is null) or a.f = :f) and ...`

If your parameter String is null then the query will check if the row's status is null as well. Otherwise it will resort to compare with the equals sign.

If you needed to skip the :status where_clause altogether; you can code like so:

`select a from A a where (:f is null or a.f = :f) and ...`

This second query is equivalent to:

```
if(status != null){
  sql.append(" a.f = :f and ");
}
```

Comment: This appears to work well when ones code is not suited to be easily switched over to the Criteria API.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't null-safe. They're translated directly to SQL, and obey the same rules. So if yo want to test for null, you must use `is [not] null`.

So if the f parameter can be null, you'll have to use two different HQL queries, or build it dynamically, or use a Criteria query to build a dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `is null` or `is not null`.
See [HQL "is null" And "!= null" on an Oracle column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066492/hql-is-null-and-null-on-an-oracle-column)

Answer (score 0):

**They are not null safe.**

HQL translates your HQL query to SQL and then it substitute your parameters.SO it won't  rewrite query from param = ? to param is null.

Go for [**Criteria API**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) and use `Restrictions.isNull("f");`

Comment: So, what happens if both are null? What is the result of =?

Comment: And how should I set the parameter to the named query? will .setString("f", null) make errors?

Comment: @Shayan: why don't you test it?

Answer (score 0):

They are not null safe. Using criteria this would do the trick

```
public static void addNullSafeEqualsRestriction(Criteria criteria, String propertyName, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull(propertyName));
    } else {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName,object));
    }
}
```