# How to pass null to SQL parameter in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle10g

I have a scenario where in i have to pass `null` to a SQL parameter through java but i am getting `SQLGrammarException`. If i am passing some value it works fine. Please guide if i am wrong somewhere.

Below is my code:

```
StringBuffer query;
    query = new StringBuffer(
    "SELECT * "+ 
         "FROM table(package.func(travel_type => travel_search_type("+
             "travel_place_no => :travelPlaceNo"+
             ")))" );
        Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString());
    query1.setParameter("travelPlaceNo",null);

    searchresults = query1.getResultList();
```

Exception:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

This is what i do through SQL Developer and it works fine:

```
    SELECT *
 FROM table(package.func(travel_type => travel_search_type(
     travel_place_no => NULL))) ;
```

Please guide.

Comment: there is a , after the :travelPlaceNo - is that a copy paste error or not?

Comment: i am sorry it was copuy paste while indenting.. corrected

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123438/hibernate-how-to-set-null-query-parameter-value-with-hql ?

Comment: I have just set null same as that was mentioned in that answer from the link but it didnt work out

Comment: Please that question has not helped my problem. Dont mark as duplicate

Comment: Atleast let me know what i have done wrong

Comment: Did you missed one closing parenthesis?

Comment: looks like there should be 3 )))

Comment: @Nick it was during identation. I am not able to pass null . if i am passing value it works fine. how to pass null. i have also shown example how i am doing in sql developer.

Comment: What database? PostgreSQL? https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9165

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: Instead of using named parameter you can try using the positional parameter. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

While calling the 2 argument signatures of the method, null is not an allowed value. You can use, instead, the 3 argument signature [setParameter(String name,
                          Object val,
                          Type type)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.type.Type)) specifying the data type and it should work.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I see there is also another problem: even if the replacemente worked, what you are trying to execute is `a >= NULL`. In this case, I'm afraid that you are going to have to handle mannually the StringBuffer creation. Maybe just force an always false condition without parameters if its null, like `1!=2', and otherwise just handle it as you are doing on your sql example (write mannually 'NULL' instead of the parameter placeholder).

Comment: What is it in the database? NUMBER? I'd just try Integer and give it a go

Comment: i am using Query query1. I didnt find those signatures.

Comment: @Rubasace If i am passing null it is throwing sqlgrammarexception bro.

Comment: Can you please give the complete classname of Query so I can check it?

Comment: javax.persistence.Query;

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829818/how-to-create-a-native-query-with-named-parameters named parameters are not supported for native queries. As @Rubasace points out, writing "NULL" directly in your query string should do the trick.

Comment: writing null gives sqlgrammarexception. I have mentioned what i have tried

Comment: "I have mentioned what i have tried". can you please give as the stacktrace and not just the exception name? Maybe that way we can help you better.

Comment: have you tried writting IS NULL / IS NOT NULL instead of >= NULL?

Comment: @Rubasace  query1.setParameter("travelPlaceNo",null); this is working fine. Is this the correct way or any better approach still there?